# Collection for storing potentially equal elements sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

i tried using TreeSet but it disallowing doubles is there a way to change that? if there is no way, what should i use for storing (equal and not equal) elements sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)  [specifically an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)] to hold the elements, and use **[`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)** to sort it when you are done populating it.

Sometimes a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is also a good option - if what you actually need is to maintain the smallest/biggest element in the collection.

If you want to maintain a sorted collection - a **[`SortedBag`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/SortedBag.html)** [from apache commons collections] might be what you are after. You can download a jar from [here](http://commons.apache.org/collections/download_collections.cgi) and add it to your classpath, and then just use it! Note that apache products are very commonly used, and thus are tested frequently!

Comment: and if i want to have it sorted all the time?

Comment: @OfekRon: Have a look at the edit [last sentence] - SortedBag might be what you are after.

Comment: it seems like it is exactly what i need, but My eclipse doesnt seem to find it...

Comment: @OfekRon: apache commons is an open source project, that though widely used, is not an official java library. You can download a jar from [here](http://commons.apache.org/collections/download_collections.cgi) and add it to your classpath, and then just use it! It'll probably be a good idea to get familiar with apache-commons, since some common features that are often used are already implemented there!

Comment: Will the @downvoter care to elaborate? The OP said it is *exactly* what he is after.

Comment: @aviad: Using a `SortedBag` is an overkill? Could you elaborate why? Your solution is basically a workaround to implement it yourself.

Comment: I think thst the problem can be easily solved by usin Java standard API. ( without Commons) Hence , it is an overkill. No hard feelings - what you suggested will work. ;)

Comment: @aviad: No hard feelings, I just don't agree. Everything can be done with [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) as well, and also with a [turing-machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). There is a reason why we prefer using existing solutions, rather then implementing them from scratch. I would always prefer to use a maintained, well-tested, existing, free and safe solution - rather then implementing it by my own.

Comment: @what are you talking about? What turing machime? For this kind of task noone needs any 3rd parties

Comment: Is there a type-safe version SortedBag<T> as well?

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer: Not that I'm aware of. I believe those should be only on the next version [3.3] of apache commons collections, could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [SortedMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html) for this purpose. It is contained in Google's Guava library which you can download at: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

If you are using Eclipse, you need to add the .jar file of Guava to the project's classpath (Right click the project, choose properties, then Java Build Path, finally add the JAR in the libraries tab).

If you don't want to use a third-party library in your project, it depends on your specific use-case what is the best option.

Comment: +1 for using existing tools. I personally prefer apache-commons, but that's only a matter of taste :)

Comment: @amit Thanks, I like your solution too. I was facing the same issue as the author of the question and was looking for a solution. I tried Guava in the end, because the Apache Commons SortedBag was not generic. (Finally I used a List and sorted after insertion, because performance was no issue.)

Comment: Note that this is only useful when the elements really *are* duplicates, as opposed to simply being sorted by a comparator that considers some of them "tied."

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` by definition doesn't allow duplicates.

You need to have a different `Comparator`, or you can use any kind of `List`.

```
SortedSet<String> temp = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComparator());
```

where `MyComparator` implements `Comparator`:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String a, String b) { ... }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is not a good approach since it is against the notion of a `Set`.Yourself specify that `by definition doesn't allow duplicates`

Comment: I agree it's not the best, but I was under the impression that the poster wanted to just extend his TreeSet. SortedBag otherwise sounds like a good solution but it's not in the standard API.

Answer (score 0):

Besides an ordered `List` you could still use a `TreeSet` but with extra space.

I.e. keep a counter for any duplicate item you would try to add in a `TreeSet`.
This approach could be implemented directly via a `TreeMap` to keep the counter for each occurenc.

This way you always know how many duplicates the user provided (counter keeps record, while TreeSet just holds the value itself).
It has the extra space overhead but with the ordered `List` you would have the overhead of preserving the ordering on additions/removals etc.
Depends on your needs.

Comment: @downvoter:Please comment as well.Otherwise what's the point?

Comment: No reason for this downvote, I got one that seems random as well. One improvement suggestion for this solution is using a `TreeMap<T,Integer>`, and maintaining the map as a histogram. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @amit:Yes `TreeMap` would be a good choice (tbh I always forget `TreeMap`)

Comment: You guys are reinventing `SortedMultiset`. You probably don't want to do that. (No, I'm not the downvoter, and don't know that person's reason.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap. In the map you store {key,value} pairs while the key is your object and the value is the number of occurencies of the key in your collection e.g you have Key "Bob" 3 times so the corresponding map entry would be {"Bob", 3} . This way you save space and achieve your goal keeping the objects sorted. Just make sure that your keys have tge equals and hashcode methods implemented. In case no natural order is availble for yiur keys ( like for strings) you will also have to implement Comparable interface for thm.

Good luck!

Comment: Many things can go wrong when you implement existing solutions yourself. There is no reason to re-invent the wheel when there are existing, well tested solutions out there.

Comment: I fail to find the correlation between your comment and my answer . What a wheel is reinvented here? I believe that it was rather a payback for me downvoting your answer... ;)

Comment: No pay-back, your comments on my answer made me aware of your answer, I approve that. While reading it, the same thing that I answered you in comments on my answer appeared - I disagree with the approach that you should implement everything from the tools you have, rather then expand your toolbox - and that is what I am referring to "reinventing the wheel" [p.s. I did not downvote your answer - so there is no retribution involved.]

Comment: When i need a class that will hold 2 strings ( first name and last name ) i create a class that has 2 string members rather than looking for a library that has it out of the box that is what the programming is about. I agree that when the task is compkicated yoy look for existing solutions but in this particular case i think that the problem can easily be solved with as little effort as described above .

Comment: well, I believe at this point we can agree on disagreeing on this subject. Happy passover! [yea I'm late] and independence day [yea I'm early]! :)